# Puppet Spec and Test kitchen

Tags: puppet, serverspec

How can I override log format of `serverspec` and extract in a separate file?
I am able to to do this but not able to extract in separate file.

My code snippet is :

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.output_stream = File.open('serverspec-result.json', 'w')
end
```

when i am running `kitchen test`, it giving me following warning :

```
RSpec's reporter has already been initialized with 
#<IO:<STDOUT>> as the output stream,
so your change to `output_stream` will be ignored. 
You should configure it earlier for it to take effect.
```